# The same exception handling, on several parts of code. Java Android

Tags: java, android, exception

I created exception that is thrown when EditText have wrong (or empty) data string.

It looks like this

```
private class NumberInputEditTextExeception extends NumberFormatException {
    public EditText editText;

    public NumberInputEditTextExeception (EditText editText) {

        this.editText = editText;
    }
}
```

And method that throws that exception :

```
private int getIntFromEditText (EditText et) throws NumberInputEditTextExeception  {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        throw new NumberInputEditTextExeception(et);
    }
}
```

And also code that handles it, and call method to show "error animation"

```
private long getEndTimeFromEditTexts () {
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int hours   = 0;

    try {
        seconds = this.getIntFromEditText(this.secondsEditText);
    } catch (NumberInputEditTextExeception e) {
        this.setErrorAnimationOnView(e.editText);
    }

    try {
        minutes = this.getIntFromEditText(this.minutesEditText);
    } catch (NumberInputEditTextExeception e) {
        this.setErrorAnimationOnView(e.editText);
    }

    try {
        hours   = this.getIntFromEditText(this.hoursEditText);
    } catch (NumberInputEditTextExeception e) {
        this.setErrorAnimationOnView(e.editText);
    }

    long endTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + (seconds * 1000) + (minutes * 1000 * 60) + (hours * 1000 * 60 * 60);

    return endTimeMs;
}
```

Can I compress anyhow, the repeating lines:

```
try {
    seconds = this.getIntFromEditText(this.secondsEditText);
} catch (NumberInputEditTextExeception e) {
    this.setErrorAnimationOnView(e.editText);
}
```

Is there any syntax that allow to do something like won't break out of whole scope (delimited by curly braces) when exception is thrown? So I could do something like this

```
specialTry () {
    seconds = this.getIntFromEditText(this.secondsEditText); // if that throws exception, it will call "catch" block and go to the next line. NOT break out of the scope.
    minutes = this.getIntFromEditText(this.minutesEditText);
    hours   = this.getIntFromEditText(this.hoursEditText);
} catch (NumberInputEditTextExeception e) {
    this.setErrorAnimationOnView(e.editText);
}
```

Or I stumbled upon this error because my design was terrible and I should change my design ?

Comment: Are you talking about putting a try-catch block inside another try block? What happened when you tried exactly that?

Comment: @kevinworkman I want to check every EditText whether or not previous have problems with parsing.

Comment: The short answer is: no, you can't compress your try-catch blocks. If you want to possibly catch an exception form each function and continue execution, you're going to have to put them in separate try blocks.

Comment: The problem is your design. You shouldn't use custom exceptions to handle UI validation errors.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin What should I use then ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular code flow instead of using the exception to trigger execution of code. Something like below

```
interface EditTextErrorHandler {
    void onError(EditText et);
}

private int getIntFromEditText (EditText et, EditTextErrorHandler handler) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        handler.onError(et);
        return 0;
    }
}

private long getEndTimeFromEditTexts () {

    EditTextErrorHandler handler = new EditTextErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onError(EditText et) {
            setErrorAnimationOnView(et);
        }
    };
    int seconds = this.getIntFromEditText(this.secondsEditText, handler);
    int minutes = this.getIntFromEditText(this.minutesEditText, handler);
    int hours   = this.getIntFromEditText(this.hoursEditText, handler);
    // values will be 0 when an error occured and the handler code is executed for each
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you change your `getIntFromEditText` method so that it does not throw an exception, but just returns `0` for an error, you can compress this code. The new method:

```
private int getIntFromEditText (EditText et) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException numberFormatException) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now your `getEndTimeFromEditTexts` method can look more like this:

```
private long getEndTimeFromEditTexts () {
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int hours   = 0;

    seconds = this.getIntFromEditText(this.secondsEditText);
    minutes = this.getIntFromEditText(this.minutesEditText);
    hours   = this.getIntFromEditText(this.hoursEditText);

    long endTimeMs = System.currentTimeMillis() + (seconds * 1000) + (minutes * 1000 * 60) + (hours * 1000 * 60 * 60);

    return endTimeMs;
}
```

The end result will do exactly what your code already did.